# File descriptor 10 when running a script (Bash/dash, etc.)

Tags: bash, shell-script, pipe, file-descriptors

When the script runs, a file descriptor 10 appears with the contents of the executable script.

For example, the script:

```bash
#!/bin/sh

sleep 600
```

When viewing the `fd` of a running script through processes, I see that fd10 appeared, with the contents of the executable script itself. Why?

Answer (score 1):

The shell reads and executes the script one statement at a time, rather than reading the entire script at startup. Therefore it needs to keep a connection to the script.

If the question is "why 10"?, then it is essentially this is "the first FD greater than 9". Historically the shell allowed you to manipulate the single digits file descriptors, e.g. 'exec 4>/dev/tty`. Modern shell's allow you to manipulate FD greater than 9.

Of course it could read everything at startup, but that would mean you couldn't usefully give things like named pipes or devices as the "script".

Comment: Why when I pass the contents of the executable script through the pipe (`cat script | sh`), instead of running the script directly, the `fd 10` with the contents of the file does not appear?

Comment: @NewLinux The script is being read from stdin, file descriptor 0, so no it will not exist on fd10.

Comment: I looked through all available descriptors of running commands/scripts - it's empty. I can assume that the pipe closed on the first call, but then why is fd10 open for reading all the time when running the script directly.